# Angular get specific value from Observable<object[]>

Tags: angular

I have created an interface like this:

```
interface channels {
    name: string;
}
```

Also I have these two variables:

```
 channelCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<channels>;
 channels: Observable<channels[]>;
```

I receive data from Firebase which I store in channels.

Afterwards I have to iterate over my  `Observable<channels[]>` and I want to log the value for the key `name` for each item. I tried the following:

```
this.channels = this.channelCollection.valueChanges();
this.channels.forEach(item => {
    const channelname = item.name;
    console.log('test', channelname);
});
```

Unfortunately it's always undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the this.channelCollection.valueChanges() method returns an Observable. It means the method is async so you must subscribe to it and operate in the proper callback.

```js
this.channelCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(channels => {
  channels.forEach(item => {
    const channelname = item.name;
    console.log('test', channelname);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The suitable rxjs operator to perform side effects is **tap**. Try this:

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.channels = this.channelCollection.valueChanges().pipe(
  tap(channels => {
     channels.forEach(item => {
       console.log('test', item.name);
     }
  )
).subscribe();
```